# WebSocket When To Use Close Handshake

Tags: go, websocket, handshake, gorilla

I'm experimenting with Gorilla WebSocket Package and I would like to know whether there is a way based on the error retrieved from `.ReadMessage` to determine whether to start the Closing Handshake (ex. 1000 - normal closure) or stop the connection immediately (ex. 1006 - abnormal closure).

Currently what I'm doing is to store the list of error codes that I might use to close the websocket connection and if an error code is equals to one of the codes in my list, I do the Closing Handshake. However I'm not sure whether this complies with the WebSocket Spec.

Is there another way to do this or this is how it is suppose to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Applications should only send close frames when the application decides to close the connection. The Gorilla package handles all other cases.

The Gorilla package sends the closing handshake on read errors. The Gorilla internal method [`handleProtocolError`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b824a5d8536651ad2d690c17e270d58855dbfd02/conn.go#L742) starts the closing handshake.

Gorilla [replies to closing handshakes from the peer application](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b824a5d8536651ad2d690c17e270d58855dbfd02/conn.go#L729).

Comment: I took a look at the [implementation of ReadMessage](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/conn.go#L823-L831) and for me at least doesn't seems to be sending any Close Frames to the connected endpoint.

Comment: By Starting the Closing Handshake I'm referring to this [section of the WebSocket RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-7.1.2)

Comment: The method [handleProtocolError](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b824a5d8536651ad2d690c17e270d58855dbfd02/conn.go#L742) sends the closing handshake.

Comment: Fine, this handles errors for when the frame being sent by the connected endpoint doesn't conform with the Web Socket spec. However if I closed the connection with Code 1000, I am responsible to implement the Closing Handshake. Or am I still wrong?

Comment: If the application decides to close the connection, then the application should start the closing handshake.  Gorilla starts the handshake on protocol errors and replies to the handshake from the peer application.